# trouble updating tail pointer in queue adt using singly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, queue

i am trying to make a queue library that is based on a linked list library i already made. specifically i am having troubles updating the tail pointer in the queue structure after i add a new node to the linked list.

linked list structure:

```
struct listNode {
    int nodeLength;
    int nodeValue;
    struct listNode *next;
};

typedef struct listNode node;
```

queue structure:

```
struct QueueRecord {
    node *list;
    node *front;
    node *back;
    int maxLen;
};
typedef struct QueueRecord queue;
```

so here is my add function in the queue library

```
void add(queue currentQueue, int data){
    addTail(currentQueue.list, data, data+5);
    currentQueue.back = currentQueue.back->next;

}
```

and the addTail function from the linked list library

```
void addTail (node *head, int value, int length) {
    node *current = head;
    node *newNode = (struct listNode *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode = initNode(value, length);

    while (current->next != NULL)   
        current = current->next;

    newNode->next = NULL;
    current->next = newNode;
}
```

so again my problem is the tail pointer is not getting set to the last node in the list. it is remaining in the same place as the head pointer. ive been researching this for hours trying to see if im just missing something small but i cant find it. if more code or explanation is needed to understand my problem i can provide it.

how a queue is created:

```
queue createQueue(int maxLen){
    queue newQueue;
    newQueue.list = createList();
    newQueue.front = newQueue.list;
    newQueue.back = newQueue.list;
    newQueue.maxLen = maxLen;
    return newQueue;
}    

node *createList (){
    node *head = NULL;
    head = (struct listNode *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    head->next = NULL;
    return head;
}

node *initNode (int value, int length){
    node *newNode = NULL;
    newNode = (struct listNode *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->nodeValue = value;
    newNode->nodeLength = length;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}
```

Comment: Added working sample to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void add(queue currentQueue, int data){
```

You are passing a *copy* of the `queue` struct to `add`, so only the copy's members are changed. You need to pass a `queue*` to the function to be able to change the members of the `queue` itself.

```
void add(queue *currentQueue, int data){
    if (currentQueue == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    addTail(currentQueue->list, data, data+5);
    currentQueue->back = currentQueue->back->next;
}
```

and call it as `add(&your_queue);`

In your `addTail` function, you should check whether `head` is `NULL` too.

And with

```
node *newNode = (struct listNode *)malloc(sizeof(node));
newNode = initNode(value, length);
```

in `addTail`, you have a serious problem. With the assignment `newNode = initNode(value, length);`, you are losing the reference to the just `malloc`ed memory.

If `initNode` `malloc`s a new chunk of memory, it's "just" a memory leak, then you should remove the `malloc` in `addTail`.

Otherwise, I fear `initNode` returns the address of a local variable, à la

```
node * initNode(int val, int len) {
    node new;
    new.nodeValue = val;
    new.nodeLength = len;
    new.next = NULL;
    return &new;
}
```

If `initNode` looks similar to that, that would cause a problem since the address becomes invalid as soon as the function returns. But your compiler should have warned you, if `initNode` looked like that.

Anyway, without seeing the code for `initNode`, I can't diagnose the cause.

But if you change your `addTail` to

```
void addTail (node *head, int value, int length) {
    if (head == NULL) { // violation of contract, die loud
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    node *current = head;
    node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (newNode == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // or handle gracefully if possible
    }
    newNode->nodeValue = value;
    newNode->nodeLength = length;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    while (current->next != NULL)   
        current = current->next;

    current->next = newNode;
}
```

it should work.

However, since you have pointers to the first and the last node in the list, it would be more efficient to use the `back` pointer to append a new node,

```
void add(queue *currentQueue, int data){
    node *newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode);
    if (newNode == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // or handle gracefully if possible
    }
    newNode->nodeValue = data;
    newNode->nodeLength = data+5;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    currentQueue->back->next = newNode;
    currentQueue->back = newNode;
}
```

since you needn't traverse the entire list to find the end.

---

A simple sample programme

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct listNode {
    int nodeLength;
    int nodeValue;
    struct listNode *next;
};

typedef struct listNode node;

struct QueueRecord {
    node *list;
    node *front;
    node *back;
    int maxLen;
};
typedef struct QueueRecord queue;

node *createList (){
    node *head = NULL;
    head = (struct listNode *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    head->next = NULL;
    return head;
}

void addTail (node *head, int value, int length) {
    if (head == NULL) { // violation of contract, die loud
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    node *current = head;
    node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (newNode == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // or handle gracefully if possible
    }
    newNode->nodeValue = value;
    newNode->nodeLength = length;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    while (current->next != NULL)   
        current = current->next;

    current->next = newNode;
}

queue createQueue(int maxLen){
    queue newQueue;
    newQueue.list = createList();
    newQueue.front = newQueue.list;
    newQueue.back = newQueue.list;
    newQueue.maxLen = maxLen;
    return newQueue;
}

void add(queue *currentQueue, int data){
    if (currentQueue == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    addTail(currentQueue->list, data, data+5);
    currentQueue->back = currentQueue->back->next;
}

int main(void) {
    queue myQ = createQueue(10);
    for(int i = 1; i < 6; ++i) {
        add(&myQ, i);
        printf("list:  %p\nfront: %p\nback:  %p\n",
                (void*)myQ.list, (void*)myQ.front, (void*)myQ.back);
    }
    node *curr = myQ.front->next;
    while(curr) {
        printf("Node %d %d, Back %d %d\n", curr->nodeValue,
                 curr->nodeLength, myQ.back->nodeValue, myQ.back->nodeLength);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    while(myQ.list) {
        myQ.front = myQ.front->next;
        free(myQ.list);
        myQ.list = myQ.front;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

works as expected, also with the alternative `add` implementation.

Comment: isn't it so, that in standard plain c, all structs are passd by reference?

Comment: No, everything is passed by value, but for arrays, a pointer to the first element is passed.

Comment: sure? so when I have sizeof(queue) := 5000 and i call fun(queue), 5000 bytes are COPYed (as you write) onto the stack? we are in C not in an onbject oriented environment, where a "copy" is put on the stack

Comment: Yes, that's it. You should pass large things by pointer for that reason.

Comment: ok i did have it set up like that before and it was causing me problems but the explanation helped me so thanks. now im not sure what my tail is pointing to because when i print the list from there it prints nothing when it should print just the last node.

Comment: @TristanPearce Well, how do you set up the `queue` initially? If you start with `NULL` pointers, you have a problem inserting the first node. If you start with a dummy `node` that `list`, `front` and `back` all point to, it should work. (By the way, I think one of `list` and `front` should be superfluous, if the two may point to different `node`s, keeping everything valid would be nontrivial.)

Comment: i added my create list function to the question

Comment: @TristanPearce How do you create/initialise the `queue`? `queue thing; thing.list = createList(); thing.front = thing.list; thing.back = thing.list;`, or how?

Comment: i call the create list for myQueue.list then set the .front and .back equal to the .list i just made

Comment: @TristanPearce Updated my answer with a problem in `addTail`. But to really find out what's going on, we need to see `initNode` too.

Comment: ok i realized my tail pointer was in the right spot after the changes it was just something in my printlist function that was incrementing the pointer to its ->next to avoid the dummie node. set up a condition so that if it was the last pointer it wouldnt do that.

Answer (score 0):

i think you never initialized back, so back->next is some random pointer?